# Nginx not serving www.example.com but serves example.com

Tags: nginx, server, config

I am having problem getting www.example.com to work. Website loads on example.com but not on www.example.com. My current config file `/etc/nginx/sites-available/example.com` is

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.example.com;
    return 301 http://example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;
    root /path/to/dir;  
    index index_en.html index.html;  
}
```

I have tried different approaches with config, none worked. I also removed the example.com block and went with only one for www.example.com, yet www.example.com didn't work, but example.com still did. Of course I restarted nginx after every change.

I have DNS records for both, example.com and www.example.com, both A and pointing to same IP. I have also tried CNAME-ing one to another, waited for few hours and nothing. Still the same. Now I am getting really pissed off, because with other subdomains everything is working perfectly, just not with www.

And yeah, if I search for www.example.com on Firefox on Ubuntu 14.04, I get Server not found.

```
# /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

user www-data;
worker_processes 4;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # nginx-naxsi config
    ##
    # Uncomment it if you installed nginx-naxsi
    ##

    #include /etc/nginx/naxsi_core.rules;

    ##
    # nginx-passenger config
    ##
    # Uncomment it if you installed nginx-passenger
    ##

    #passenger_root /usr;
    #passenger_ruby /usr/bin/ruby;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

I left mail section out because it is completely commented out.

Comment: Need some debugging info. `host www.example.com`, `host example.com` see both are giving same IP or not. Next post your config nginx config and not just part of it

Comment: I realised there has to be a problem in DNS service because everything is working perfectly. And yes, I tried `host www.example.com` and no output, meaning it isn't registered, although I registered it yesterday and maximum time they allow for changes to take effect are 4 hours... Will have to call them I guess.

Comment: Make sure you have a `@` entry in your DNS zone, which is for the root domain

Comment: Here are my relevant DNS entries:
(name                    type      destination)
||| example.com.        A           IP |||
test.example.com. A           IP |||
*.example.com.     CNAME example.com. |||
It might be the problem that DNS service is automatically adding '.' at the end of everything? And test.example.com is working perfectly. I also tried with www.example.com instead of *, nothing worked. Also tried ||| *.example.com A IP ||| and ||| www.example.com A IP |||, nothing...

Comment: The dot at the end is a standard format for DNS zone files. But if you are not getting IP for example.com, then contact your domain provider

Comment: At home I never used dot and everything works perfectly, with different domains, subdomains, internal proxies etc.. I have my IP and I have it set where IP is written, for example if my external IP is 12.34.56.789, then I have DNS entry as example.com A 12.34.56.789. Not sure exactly what you meant by " if you are not getting IP for example.com". I will post nginx config now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153333/discussion-between-tarun-lalwani-and-campovski).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It probably had to do with some local DNS settings on LAN and local DNS cache, because I was able to access the site from other networks.